# How to create a slow view?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I want to test the timeout-behavior of my MS-Access application (with linked tables). It would be super convenient to have a slow database query. If possible, even with a predefined query duration.

I tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW slow_view AS
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:05'
SELECT 1 AS one
```

but `WAITFOR` is not allowed inside a tsql view definition.

How can I create a slow database view in SQL Server, that provokes a timeout?

Comment: A `VIEW` is simply a virtual table defined by a `SELECT`. It can't have commands like an `WAITFOR`, it can literally have a single statement that results in a `SELECT`. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) but if you must do this, use a different object type like a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Larnu MS-Access linked tables can only be tables or views. Stored procedures are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to lock a table.
In SSMS or a different tool, execute a query with a begin transaction, but don't include the commit or rollback.

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT *
FROM MyTable with(tablockx)
```

Then try to access the same table from a different session, it will wait until the transaction is completed / rollbacked.

In action in SSMS, left side is the locking query, right side is the blocked query.
[image: SSMS]

To stop the blocking query, you can execute `COMMIT` in the locking query session, by selecting the `COMMIT` and executing it <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Super convenient, because I can manually define, when I want the query to return. Alternatively one could put a `WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:05' ROLLBACK` after the select, for a predefined duration.

Comment: Rollbacks are mostly single threaded, so it's better to commit. For this statement it doesn't  matter, since the transaction log stays untouched, but for future reference.